# Is it necessary to have at least one `H1` in any webpage?

Tags: xhtml, usability, accessibility, screen-readers

Is it necessary to have at least one `H1` in any **web page**? in terms of **accessibility**, **semantics** and **SEO**.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necssary. Ask the same question about other tags, is it necessary to have a < H2 > tag?

That being said, the < h1 > tag is meant as the main heading, so if styled correctly should add a main focus point to your page.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah It's not necessary however it's not unnecessary. I mean technically its not necessary to have img tags or a tags for that matter. And if you wan't to be really technical, you don't even NEED html tags most browsers will still render the page, but that's extremely bad practice. H1 tags cab be useful actually, specificially with css, as an additional p tag.

Comment: Haha i guess you got a lot of answers defining 'necessary.' Sorry about that. While still not 'necessary' for SEO, google assumes text between h1 tags is more important than say text between p tags.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to have at least one but it is necessary as advocated by seo guys not to put more than one `<h1>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

only for seo.
it is THOUGHT (for high rankings in google) that the TEXT LINK TO a page should be found in the `<h1></h1>` AND in the `<title></title>` and should come up a couple of time in the text.